# How to implement an ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker

I would like to implement "ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker" in my project. For that I've referred this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker)

Firstly I've installed the date picker using the statement

```
npm install ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker --save
```

This is my **app.component.ts** file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { DateTimePickerDirective } from 'ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker/dist/datetimepicker.directive';
import 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-root',
  template: ` <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  options = {
    format: "DD.MM.YYYY"
  };
}
```

This is my **app.module.ts** file

```
-----------------------
import { DateTimePickerDirective } from 'ng2-eonasdan-datetimepicker/dist/datetimepicker.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   -------------
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ---------------
    ---------------
    DateTimePickerDirective
  ],
  providers: [HeroService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my **Index** page

```
 <my-root>Loading...</my-root>

  <div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group"
        a2e-datetimepicker
        [date]="dateTo"
        [options]="a2eOptions"
        (onChange)="dateToChange($event)"
        (onClick)="dateClick()">
  <input class="form-control"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
</div>
```

There is no such error is getting with this code but date picker is not rendering. If you have any idea please help me.

Comment: Well, this repository seems to be outdated. I'd recommend you to see [**this one**](https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker).

Comment: @developer033 - I've tried this. Its working fine, but its binding an object of data to the ng-model instead of a date string